# Sending Auto Message in Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, geolocation, gps, sms

I am trying to develop an application in android using eclipse . This application is like finding the friend location and directions using android mobile .

I am doing this in a way :
First this application is installed in user and friend both , when the user wants to retrieve the location of the friend , in our application we want a auto-message to be sent to the friend which asks his permission .If he gives it  , a message containing the location(latitude, longitude) of friend goes to user and then He gets the location and path to that friend .

Now Getting the location part in a mobile having the This application has been done .
But The auto messaging part is still incomplete .
So if anyone can tell me any tutorial or sample code to sent auto messages( like in facebook we do add as a friend and a message is sent for the approval )

All of this is done through GPS .

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of examples over the net on how to send automated sms messages. Here are a few i found courtesy google..
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/
Basically you need to know how to use intents and BroadcastReceivers that will listen to particular events and send the text message, and do particular actions when sms is received also.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a server that sits between the two phone as an intermediary. You can have the first phone send a request to the server saying "Hey, where's friend X". The server can then use something like android [Cloud To Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) to push a query to the friends phone. Then on the friends phone, have an activity pop up asking for permission to send the location. A message containing the location can then be sent back to the server and pushed to the first device using C2DM again.